# Why is struct containing single char not padded to size 4 on a 32-bit system?

Tags: c, struct, padding, sizeof

```
struct test {
    char c;
} x;
```

From my knowledge of structure padding, I expected the size of this structure to be 4 Bytes on a 32-bit system. Why does it show 1 byte?

Comment: Because it is efficiently accessed at *any* address. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813803/structure-padding

Answer (score 0):

You just have a char, in that case you won't need any alignment/padding.
If you try this you should see some alignment:

```
char *p;      /* 4 or 8 bytes */
char c;       /* 1 byte */
//char pad[3];  /* 3 bytes */
int x;        /* 4 bytes */
```

There are different rules for different architectures, in this case the int has a 4byte alignment, which forces a padding of three bytes to be added.

source:
http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Answer (score -1):

In C, the strucute are padded to the current data size.
If you have a char will be aligned to 1B, for short to 2B and so on.

A quick rule is: size of previous elements + size of current element aligned to size of current element .

Here are some exaples:

```
struct
{
    int  a1; // 0 + 4 aligned to 4 => 4
    char a2; // 4 + 1 aligned to 1 => 5
} // total size 5

struct 
{
    char a1; // 0 + 1 aligned to 1 => 1
    int a2; // 1 + 4 aligned to 4 => 8
}

struct
{
    char a1; // 0 + 1 aligned to 1 => 1
    short a2; // 1 + 2 aligned to 2 => 4
    int a3; // 4 + 4 aligned to 4 => 8
}
```

This rule is an effect of memory addressing:
Fastest way to read/write X byte memory is if that memory address is multiple of X. (This is how Intel processors optimise memory access by ignoring some bits of addressing).

Another padding is between structures in memory. If you have a structure with an `int` and a `char`(total size 5), in memory you will still have 3 bytes padding between them for memory access optimisation.